# What is the difference between defining an object using ={} and defining using = new Object()?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm unclear on the different syntax used to define objects. What is the difference (if any) between defining an object like this:

```
var myObject = {}
```

and like this:

```
var myObject = new Object();
```

In the admittedly fairly straightforward examples I've worked on I can't yet see a difference in behaviour between the two. It seems to be possible to access and manipulate both objects in the same ways. However, I see both examples used so I assume there is some difference between the two.

Comment: From [ECMAScript 5, 11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5): *The production... `{ }` is evaluated as follows: Return a new object created as if by the expression `new Object()`...*

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the dupe question on this. Didn't show up when I posted for some reason.

Comment: Just saying: this question is clearer, cleaner and more generic than its duplicate.

Comment: @gideon I'd tend to agree; this question is very well-written. I think it's easier to clean up that question than to try to divert the moment from that question here, though. (I'll take a pass at cleaning up that question now.)

Comment: @apsillers I put that in there because I really don't want this question being deleted. It serves as an excellent [sign-post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). Also the title is excellent and methinks will show up easier on googling.